# Почему в лингвистике считается, что "текст" может быть устной речью?

Tags: значение-слов, терминология, значение, термины, текст

Если взять словарь Ожегова:

> текст, -а, м. 1. Всякая записанная речь (литературное произведение,
> сочинение, документ, а также часть, отрывок из них). Т. сочинений
> Пушкина. Подлинный т. Т. оперы. Открытым текстам сообщить, передать
> что-н. (не секретно; также перен.: прямо, недвусмысленно). 2. В
> лингвистике: внутренне организованная последовательность отрезков
> письменного произведения или записанной либо звучащей речи,
> относительно законченной по своему содержанию и строению. Теория
> текста. 3. В полиграфии: основная часть печатного набора (без
> иллюстраций, чертежей, таблиц). ◊ Нотный текст — нотная запись
> музыкального произведения. || прил. текстовой, -ая, -ое и текстовый,
> -ая, -ое.

Такими образом, исходя их первого определения: «Всякая записанная речь», текст — это письменная речь. Я так и думал до тех пор, пока не столкнулся с тем, что в лингвистике текстом могут считать устную речь и даже мысли.

У того же Ожегова:

> 2. В лингвистике: внутренне организованная последовательность отрезков письменного произведения или записанной либо **звучащей речи**,
>    относительно законченной по своему содержанию и строению. Теория
>    текста.

В Википедии хотя сначала написано:

> Текст (от лат. textus — ткань; сплетение, сочетание) — зафиксированная
> на каком-либо материальном носителе человеческая мысль; в общем плане
> связная и полная последовательность символов.

Т.е. всё-таки «зафиксированная на каком-либо материальном носителе».

Потом написано:

> В лингвистике термин «текст» используется в широком значении, включая
> и образцы **устной речи**.

Устной речи?! Это как? Устная речь — это одно, а текст (письменная речь) — это другое.

Почему в лингвистике устная речь считается тоже текстом?

Comment: "Устная речь — это одно, а текст (письменная речь) — это другое". Откуда вы это взяли? Текст — это "сочетание" по-латински. В лингвистике именно в этом значении слово и употребляется: "сочетание слов", а уж написаны они или произнесены, это не так уж и важно. Лингвист изучает и то, и это. Просто для вас слышать слово "текст" в таком значении непривычно. А пожарные называют шланг "рукавом", и это тоже режет слух очень многим. А художники "пишут" картины, хотя для обывателя они рисуют, а пишут только буквы. Просто примите как факт, что на языке специалистов слова могут употребляться в непривычно

Comment: Откуда я это взял? Я написал для примера первое определение Ожегова: «текст — всякая записанная речь (литературное произведение, сочинение, документ, а также часть, отрывок из них). Т. сочинений Пушкина. Подлинный т. Т. оперы...» Но такое понимание есть не только в этом словаре. Вы хотите сказать, что текст в понимании как письменной, так и устной речи — это часть жаргона лингвистов? Может быть и так. Но тогда возникает вопрос, как дать определение такому понятию. Сочетание слов — это слишком широко, это и предложение, и фразеологизм, и фраза, и словосочинение. Любое сочетание слов это текст?

Comment: Я думаю, что в подавляющем большинстве случаев правильным определением будет нечто вроде: "Письменное сочетание слов, обладающее структурой и как правило передающее информацию".  А устный, нотный текст — это уже специфическое, то есть то, что в словарях идёт под вторым и третьим значением, ведь слова не универсальны. Найдите универсальное значение слова "язык". Есть русский язык, есть язык костра, есть язык колокола, есть язык как часть тела. Их нельзя обобщить универсальным определением. Текст тоже нельзя.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но к сожалению, это не определение, которое полностью отражает понятие лингвистического текста, о котором мы говорим. В нём говорится только про письменный текст. Слова многозначны, но меня интересует конкретное значение. Как понимать «как правило передающее информацию». Бывает текст, информацию не передающий? А зачем тогда он нужен?

Comment: Я вот нашёл вроде неплохое определение: «Текст — это реально высказанное (написанное) предложение или совокупность предложений, ... могущее ... служить материалом для наблюдения фактов данного языка». Традиционно в лингвистике термином «текст» обозначают не только записанный, зафиксированный так или иначе текст, но и любое кем-то созданное «речевое произведение» любой протяжённости — от однословной реплики до целого рассказа, поэмы или книги. [studbooks.net](https://studbooks.net/836456/literatura/ponyatie_teksta_lingvistike)

Comment: При этом указано, что «Текст представляет собой фиксированное законченное сообщение»  [studbooks.net](https://studbooks.net/836456/literatura/ponyatie_teksta_lingvistike). 
**Я понимаю так: «текст» в лингвистике — это любая высказанная речь устно или письменно, от как минимум одного предложения и до бесконечности предложений, которая представляет собой законченное сообщение.** Что думаете о таком определении?

Comment: Да, бывает текст не передающий информацию и обращённый к ассоциативной интерпретацию. Бывает даже текст чисто визуальный, состоящий из вымышленных слов или даже вымышленных букв. Например, у Кэрролла: "варькалось, хлипкие шарьки пырялись по наве..." или как-то так. Это текст? Текст! А информацию он передаёт? Нет. но всё равно текст.

Comment: "Что думаете о таком определении?". Что оно не охватывает весь необходимый диапазон значений, а условие о минимум одном предложении вообще нахожу нелепым. И определение о законченном сообщении, кстати, тоже.

Comment: А какие именно случаи оно не охватывает? Приведите, пожалуйста, примеры для понимания. Приведете, также пример текста в котором не ни одного предложения.

Comment: "А какие именно случаи оно не охватывает?" . Случаи, когда текст является не законченным сообщением, но остаётся текстом. "Приведете, также пример текста в котором не ни одного предложения". 1) Вопрос из опросника, где стоят три точки, а респонденту нужно дописать ответ 2)повреждённый пергамент, где отсутствуют фрагменты слов, и др.

Comment: *«2)повреждённый пергамент, где отсутствуют фрагменты слов, и др.»*— то, что там написано когда-то было текстом, и это можно назвать остатками текста. Насчёт многоточия вопрос интересный. Суть многоточия именно в том, чтоб заменить пропуск в тексте и сообщение выглядело законченным. Если многоточия не будет, тогда это нельзя будет назвать текстом. Читая текст «Меня зовут…» человек получает законченное сообщение: «Тут нужно вписать имя». Если будет просто «Меня зовут», то тут сообщение не законченное, потому что вообще непонятно, что хотели сказать этим.

Comment: 1) Ладно, замените историю с опросником на ситуацию, где писатель умер, недописав не только предложение, но и слово на середине. У вас 20 листов из книги, где предполагалось 202. Его мысль осталась незаконченной, фраза оборвана на середине слова. Восстановить смысл нельзя. Нельзя лишить рукопись статуса текста только из-за того, что мысль в ней не закончена. 2) Пергамент может быть имитацией, созданной для квеста, мистификации или как сувенир, либо как изделие художника. Текст в полном виде при таких условиях никогда не существовал.

Comment: Это мы уже уходим в глубокие копания. Можно ли назвать недособранный самолёт, который стоит на закрывшемся заводе 20 лет, самолётом. Сомнительно. Это можно назвать незавершённым самолётом, как и можно говорить о незавершённом произведении автора, незавершённом тексте рукописи и т. п.

Comment: Теперь по поводу непринятых ответов. Вопрос был: *«Почему в лингвистике считается, что „текст“ может быть устной речью?»*. Ваши тезисы: **1. Откуда вы взяли, что текст это письменная речь**, хотя я привёл общеупотребильное значение текста из словаря. **2. Текст это сочетание слов**, что спорно, и к тому же, что будет, если как вы говорите автор не дописал слово и скончался на последней букве поражённый ударом молнии, что тогда? **3. «для вас слышать слово „текст“ в таком значении непривычно»** — это ваше субъективное суждение, которое вообще не имеет отношения к ответу на вопрос. (часть 1/2)

Comment: **4. «на языке специалистов слова могут употребляться в непривычном для вас значении»** — я не спрашивал о том, могут или не могут, этот тут не к чему. **5. «Просто примите как факт...»** — я не обращался за наставлением. Таким образом я ответа на вопрос не получил, кроме вашего мнения, что «текст — это сочетание слов». Я хочу получить более аргументированный ответ, с аргументацией именно ответа, а не того, что мне нужно делать. (часть 2/2)

Comment: "Это мы уже уходим в глубокие копания". В этом нет проблемы. "Сомнительно". Только для вас. Если есть возражения, озвучте. 1) "Я привёл общеупотребильное значение текста из словаря". Одно из значений. 2) "что спорно", спорьте, но слово всё равно слово, даже не целое 3) "это ваше субъективное суждение", это вывод на основе ваших доводов. ,4) "я не спрашивал", зато непонимание этого привело вас к неверным выводам. Вы всё время уводите вопрос в неверное русло, ища, вероятно, ответ, который уже сами себе загадали. Самолёт в любой готовности самолёт, потому что ему предстоит ИДЕЯ самолёта.

Comment: «Одно из значений» ну конечно одно, я же сказал, что привёл общеупотребительное значение. Другие значения там специальные: в лингвистике и в полиграфии.

Comment: Понятие представляет собой совокупность признаков присущих всем объектам, которое под него подпадают. Если каких-то признаков нет, значит объект нельзя относить к этому понятию. Слово является обозначением понятия, и если слово не полное, значит непонятно какое понятие оно обозначает, и это не слово. Самолётом можно назвать только то, что обладает признаками самолёта. Если у него, например, ещё нет крыльев, это не самолёт. Это можно назвать заготовкой самолета, но не самолетом. «Зато непонимание этого привело вас к неверным выводам» — это вы так решили. Ответа нет.

Comment: "Понятие представляет собой совокупность признаков присущих всем объекта", человек, не обладающий ногой, не человек? А текст, в котором ради эффекта старины повреждена часть слов, не текст? Мне с вашей логикой всё понятно. "привёл общеупотребительное значение". Ага, привели, а сперва просили объяснить вам лингвистическое. Зачем вы скачите с темы на тему? Определитесь уже, что именно вас интересует: или общеупотребительное, или узкое значение.

Comment: Нога не является необходимым признаком человека, а крылья являются необходимым признаком самолёта. Я сперва привёл общеупотребительное, в котором только письменная речь, потом привёл лингвистическое, в котором есть и устная речь, а потом спросил почему в лингвистике устная речь считается тоже текстом. Перечитайте мой вопрос. Суть вопроса была именно в отличии понимания лингвистами текста, и почему так.

Comment: Я больше не буду продолжать диалог, потому что это не имеет никакого отношения к ответу на вопрос. До свиданья. Удачи вам в ваших изысканиях.

Comment: "Почему в лингвистике устная речь считается тоже текстом" и получили ответ: потому что это слово употреблено в разных значениях, и "текст" здесь восходит к его изначальному латинскому смыслу. Но у вас спор ради спора. Про самолёт ерунду говорите. Есть бескрылые самолёты. Главное ИДЕЯ предмета, а не его состояние.